# Still Custom template displays on emptying cart also

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to override cart page for developing an extension. Everything works fine but when I empty my cart it still displays custom template file. It is not displaying the empty cart page.

Here is my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate"><value>module/checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
             <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>module/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
              <block type="module/list" name="module_list" template="module/checkout/list.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount">
                    <columns>4</columns></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

If I change the action method of the cart.phtml from "setTemplate" to "setCartTemplate" then it is not displaying the custom template. It is displaying the template from the default folder (Right now I am working at base folder). Here is the screenshot when I made cart page empty. Any idea on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The XML looks correct. Maybe if there is a PHP error in your template file Magento will fall back to the base phtml file. So perhaps a quick check in the error logs or change your noItems.phtml to something simple to test it eg

```
<?php echo("my template is here"); ?>
```

I note that the filename noItems.phtml is unusual because of the capital 'I' in Items so just double check your file is exactly called 'noItems.phtml' ;-)

***EDITS following comment below.

It is hard to debug why a file isn't being used. I would be putting some echo or logging statements into:

```
//file: app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart.php
//class: Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart
//function: chooseTemplate()
    public function chooseTemplate()
    {
        $itemsCount = $this->getItemsCount() ? $this->getItemsCount() : $this->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
        if ($itemsCount) {
            $this->setTemplate($this->getCartTemplate());
        } else {
            $this->setTemplate($this->getEmptyTemplate());
        }
    }
```

Have you turned on the template hints from the system configuration? It might help expose a block or a template.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Template file name is fine. No issues with that. I have tried to set template from controller and also tried to set from block. But it is just calling the template file from the default folder

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="checkout.cart">
    <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>module/checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
    <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>module/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
    <action method="chooseTemplate"/> <== ADD THIS
</reference>
```

Comment: Please add some details about your answer.